# How make a nested / indented text list using MUI Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following data structure:

```
const bullets = [
"Top Sports are:",
"hockey",
"soccer",
"football",
"Top Names are:",
"liam",
"noah",
"jordan"
]
```

I am able to make a bulleted list using MUI's typography comoponent like so:

```
import { Typography } from 'components/Typography'
//...

<div >
  {bullets.map((bullet: string, index: any) => (
    <Typography key={index} component='li' variant='body2'>
      {bullet}
    </Typography>
     )
)}
</div>
```

However, I would like to change the data structure to have arrays for the nested/indented lists like so:

```
const nestedBullets = [
"Top Sports are:",
["hockey","soccer","football"],
"Top Names are:",
["liam","noah","jordan"]
]
```

But I don't know how to adapt the original code to deal with the nested lists so they appear like this rather than a flat bulleted list:

```
 - Top Sports are:
    - hockey
    - soccer
    - football
 - Top Names are:
    - liam
    - noah
    - jordan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with @Hatana answer is that it does not include the usage of Mui Typography as per the question but it's on the right path.

Here is my solution... I've written in typescript so replace it with JS if required. This also accounts for nesting multiple levels dictated by the data structure passed in for "infinite" nesting.

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  const nestedBullets = [
    "Top Sports are:",
      ["hockey", "soccer", "football"],
    "Top Names are:",
      ["liam", "noah", "jordan", ["stacy", "becky", ["miah", "julie", "tracy"]]]

  ]
  return (<ListComponent items={nestedBullets} />)
}


type DataTree<T> = T | Array<DataTree<T>>
type Data = DataTree<string>
type ListComponentProps = { items: Data[] }

const ListComponent = ({ items }: ListComponentProps) => (
  <Typography component="ul" >
    {
      items.map((item, index) =>
        (typeof item === "string") ?
          <Typography key={index} component="li">{item}</Typography> :
          <ListComponent key={index} items={item} />)
    }
  </Typography>
)

export default App;
```

Displays as like the following, apply your own styles .

**Renders:**

[image: What you are asking]

**"Infinite" nesting levels:**

```js
  const nestedBullets = [
    "Top Sports are:",
      ["hockey", "soccer", "football"],
    "Top Names are:",
    ["liam", "noah", "jordan",
      ["stacy", "becky",
        ["miah", "julie", "tracy"]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

[image: Infinite nesting levels]

Note: The `ListCoponent` expects an `Array` to be passed for the `items` prop.

Comment: I think you all mind about `Typography` lol so I added it it is a small detail tho

Answer (score 0):

one solution I can think of is to create a component that accepts an array of items as props and then display it with the `map()` method, for each iteration checks if the item is an array so it recursively calls itself otherwise directly display it:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const nestedBullets = [
    "Top Sports are:",
    ["hockey", "soccer", "football"],
    "Top Names are:",
    ["liam", "noah", "jordan"],
  ];

  return <NestedList items={nestedBullets} />;
};


const NestedList = ({ items }) => (
  <>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {Array.isArray(item) ? (
          <ul>
            <NestedList items={item} />
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <li>
            <Typography component="li" variant="body2">
              {item}
            </Typography>
          </li>
        )}
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Comment: What is the parent component doing here? looks like it is unused

Comment: the parent component is actualy the component you are using just create another component `NestedList` then pass `items={nestedBullets}` to it and let it do the work of displaying the array

Comment: you create `NestedList` then instead of doing `bullets.map....` you juste use `<NestedList items={bullets} />;`

Comment: Oh i see, i am trying to test it now. Just translating it to typescript which is rather tricky cause of the `items` part

Comment: your real use case may be more complicated but here types are simple `items` is `(string | string[])[]` and `item`  is  `string | string[]`

Comment: [TsPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oGdgCcCWA7A5lAD7pZ74DaAugFA0DGA9rhlLhBhACYBCArgBsBEYGgBcseAmoooFGgCIAKozBQAymEaZRUAIaYIYhQBoaFBQAtG9ANYQQphWhv0ImJwDNGjYACM9IQUqM2VVKAA5PQQOfUNjMwsBbGinXEY9SycAK20uPVxgmiogA)

Comment: I see, for some reason i cant type it that way:
`({ items }: (string | string[])[]): JSX.Element `
maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: `const NestedList: React.FC<NestedListProps> = ({ items }) => (<ul>...</ul>)`

Comment: with `interface NestedListProps { items: (string | string[])[]; }`

Comment: Okay your solution, almost works, here is the result: https://pasteboard.co/ytkWzmAqa67S.png

Comment: @guy have a look I updated my answer this looks better

Comment: @asbai that works but you removed the typography styling which is the problem i am trying to solve. Making the nested list with typography styling

Comment: Bro, just use typography  instead of div

Comment: Now you got the idea you can manage that

Comment: @guy just added typography to the solution you may need another typography for the `<ul>`